# Add a quadratic random effect to a nonlinear mixed model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, nonlinear

How can one add a quadratic random effect to a nonlinear mixed effect model? I've been trying to do this with nlmer without luck. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit: as diagnosed by Ben, the root problem is that I am trying to shoehorn a numeric variable into the role of a (categorical, non-numeric) grouping variable.**

Here's my starting point that works fine:

`nlmem <- nlmer(value ~ nfun(x, y0) ~  (y0|site) + (y0|gas:CTG), data=data.plot, start=initial.guesses)`

...and my failed attempts upon changing the formula to include a quadratic random effect:

```
value ~ nfun(x, y0) ~  (y0|site) + (y0|gas:CTG) + (y0|CTG*CTG)
    Error: Invalid grouping factor specification, CTG * CTG
    In addition: Warning message:
    In Ops.factor(CTG, CTG) : * not meaningful for factors

value ~ nfun(x, y0) ~  (y0|site) + (y0|gas:CTG) + (y0|poly(CTG, 2))
    Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor poly(CTG, 2) within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
    2: In Ops.factor(x, xbar) : - not meaningful for factors

value ~ nfun(x, y0) ~  (y0|site) + (y0|gas:CTG) + (y0|I(CTG^2))
    Error: Invalid grouping factor specification, I(CTG^2)
    In addition: Warning message:
    In Ops.factor(CTG, 2) : ^ not meaningful for factors
```

CTG is numeric, not a factor. Not sure why the error message is complaining about it being a factor.

> ```
> class(data.plot$CTG) 
> [1] "numeric"
> ```

Comment: Why are you using `nlmer`? What exactly do you mean by nonlinear? Can you write out the function you want to fit?

Comment: The fixed effect `nfun` is a Lorentzian, the parameters of which are being fitted, so nonlinear and not separable into a linear additive model, if that's what you're getting at. I'm using `nlmer` since it can handle the nonlinear fixed effect plus random effects. Other suggestions are welcome, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `CTG` is numeric you shouldn't be using it as a *grouping variable* (the right-hand side of a `(f|g)` random effect specification).  A grouping variable (`g`) should always be a categorical/factor variable, or something that can meaningfully be coerced to such.

A possible reason for such a confusion is that, for a *categorical* effect `f`,

- `(1|f:g)` describes the variation among categories within groups (a single variance parameter);
- `(f|g)` describes the variation among *effects* across groups (i.e., a variance-covariance matrix among the baseline group and differences among groups).  If this variance-covariance matrix is restricted to a *positive compound-symmetric structure*, e.g.

$$
\Sigma = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} \sigma^2 &  \rho \sigma^2 &    \rho \sigma^2 & \ldots \\
                                    \rho  \sigma^2    & \sigma^2 & \rho  \sigma^2& \ldots \\ 
                                    \vdots   & \vdots   & \vdots & \ddots 
                 \end{array} \right)
$$

(with $\rho>0$; notation isn't perfect, but you get the idea) -- this is theoretically possible, but not in `lme4` at the moment -- then you would get exactly the same answer.

Traditionally, with models that only allow among-group differences in the intercept, people have gotten used to thinking about `(1|f:g)` as the way to model an interaction between a categorical (fixed-effect) predictor and a random grouping variable, so the distinction between effects and grouping variables tends to get blurred.

I think you're looking for a *random (quadratic) slopes* model, i.e. if `nfun` is a quadratic function `a+b*x+c*x^2` then you would use

```
 value ~ nfun(x, a,b,c) ~ (a+b+c|site)
```

(although for a polynomial model you could just use a linear mixed model with `x` and `I(x^2)` terms).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. `CTG` is numeric but I am using it categorically as it takes only 3 levels. There is super-linear sensitivity the value of `CTG`, hence my attempt to construct a model with a quadratic random effect. Following your notation, is it possible to solve a model of the form `value ~ nfun(...) ~ (f|I(g^2)` in `nlmer`? (i.e. does `nlmer` support such a construct with the grouping variable squared?)

Comment: I'm confused.  If you want to use `CTG` categorically, coerce it to a factor (I would do this via `transform(data.plot,fCTG=factor(CTG))` and then use `fCTG` or interactions therewith as your grouping variable). However, if you're really treating `CTG` as categorical, then there's no such thing as "quadratic variation" (in the model, each distinct value of `CTG` leads to a different expected response, with no linear *or* quadratic structure). Maybe making `CTG` an *ordered* factor (leading to polynomial contrasts) and treating it as an effect would make sense?)

Comment: suppose the values of `g` are 1,2,3.  Now square it -- you get values 1,4,9 -- and treat it as categorical -- and you have the *same* categorical variable as you would have gotten treating `g` as categorical (but with labels changed from "1", "2", "3" to "1", "4", "9" ...)

Comment: Got it. Squaring `g` only relabels the values, as you note, and the grouping is still done on the same number of levels as with the unsquared value. I'll take a step back and consider how to move `g` out of a grouping role. Many thanks!